# libvirt custom emulator path

Tags: virtualization

I'm having a problem configuring custom path to `qemu-system-x86_64`.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/TEST:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
$ which qemu-system-x86_64
/usr/local/TEST/qemu-system-x86_64
```

Seems to work in console.
But after restarting libvirt, I can see following errors in syslog:

```
libvirt version: 2.5.0, package: 3ubuntu5.5~cloud0 (Openstack Ubuntu Testing Bot <openstack-testing-bot@ubuntu.com> Fri, 18 Aug 2017 13:59:48 +0000)    
Cannot check QEMU binary /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: No such file or directory
```

This causes libvirt to give empty capabilities. 
Is there any trick to make $PATH work? 
I don't see any hard-coded paths in source code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this seems not libvirt related after all.
This is a way systemd works.
Systemd ignores default environment variables. It also ignores `/etc/environment` settings.
You have to explicitly configure libvirt-bin service file to contain variables you require:

```
[Service]
Environment="PATH=/usr/local/TEST:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin"
```

You can also specify default environment file:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
```

Things you learn each day...